# TGV Lyria seat plan: how to interpret it?

Tags: france, seating, high-speed-rail

I'm taking a look at the [seat plan](http://www.tgv-lyria.com/main/FCK/File/site_en/the_journey/on_board/seating_plan.asp) for the Zurich-Paris TGV Lyria.

The diagrams only show cars from 1 to 8, but the text says that cars are numbered 1-8 and 11-18. Is car 11 the same thing as car 1, car 12 same as car 2, and so on?

Most of the seats are marked by two numbers, e.g. 75/54 -- what does it mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are incorrect, cars are *not* numbered 1-8 **and** 11-18, they are numbered 1-8 **or** 11-18.

From the webpage you link to:

> coach 1 to 8 or coach 11 to 18.

On any given trip, the cars will be either 1-8 or 11-18. For the purposes of selecting a seat 1 and 11 are then the same as are 2 and 12 etc.

As for the two numbers, it seems to have to do with the direction of travel. The diagrams are not going to be an exact representation of the carriages (as they have multiple rolling stock, that do vary). But seat number XX in carriage Y should be of a certain type (e.g. window seat versus isle etc.)

Comment: Yes, I think you're right; if you turn the carriage the other way around, you use the other set of numbers.

Comment: The strange thing is that if you select the plan for the Paris-Bern service, then each seat has only one number. Don't they turn it the other way round?

Comment: Sets aren't turned around. However, only the POS sets used on services to Zürich have those double seat numbers, which allow them to revers the numbering depending on direction of travel. On the Bern - Paris service older sets are used, where this is not done.

Comment: Yup - that's the reason on (most) trains in France you can't book "forward facing" seats.  You can only do that on, those few trains with the digital-changeable seat numbers.

Answer (score 3):

> carriages are numbered as follows: coach 1 to 8 **or** coach 11 to 18

Note that's "or", not "and" - TGVs are sometimes joined together in pairs (not on the Lyria routes, but the trains are the same trains) and then one train is 1-8 and the other is 11-18.

So yes, 1 and 11 are the same, etc.

I can't explain the two different numbers.